# Animate floating action button expanded <-> normal

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, floating-action-button

I'm trying to animate between the different states of expanded and normal but it doesn't look good.

This is how I'm doing it:

normal

```
button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon"), for: .normal)
button.setMode(.normal, animated: animated)
```

expanded

```
button.setTitle("title", for: .normal)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon"), for: .normal)
button.setMode(.expanded, animated: animated)
```

The animation in particular doesn't look good when going from expanded to normal, see attached [video.](https://ufile.io/cl122dz4)

### Platform (please complete the following information)

- Device: iPhoneSE
- OS: iOS14.5
- MaterialComponents/Buttons (109.4.0)

Comment: It will be better if you also share what's happening inside 'setMode' method.

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/blob/8ebb509555666645a4bc7b64e5c83408be80fe2e/components/Buttons/src/MDCFloatingButton.m#L368